# How to calculate the percentage of employee type in OTBI Report?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have tried a lot of methods using count and sum. An example table can be the following:

| Name | Employee Type | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | E | 66.6 |
| Second | E | 66.6 |
| Third | E | 66.6 |
| Fourth | E | 66.6 |
| Fifth | C | 33.3 |
| Sixth | C | 33.3 |

I have tried using column formula like this: COUNT(COUNT("Worker"."Person Number") by "Worker"."Assignment Type")*100 /COUNT(*)

But I believe that the first count shouldn't be there and if I use it without it, OTBI gives me a syntax error. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using analytic functions here:

```sql
SELECT Name, "Employee Type",
       100.0 * (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "Employee Type") /
                COUNT(*) OVER () ) AS Percentage
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY "Employee Type", Name;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cd160588dc29663a31df4350eedd73f) for Oracle.

If for some reason you can't use analytic functions, then a join approach also works here:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name, t1."Employee Type",
       100.0 * t2.cnt / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable) AS Percentage
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT "Employee Type", COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY "Employee Type"
) t2
    ON t2."Employee Type" = t1."Employee Type"
ORDER BY "Employee Type", Name;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As per my knowledge of Oracle OTBI, over() cannot be used. So I tried the closest alternative to your statement which was 100* (COUNT("Worker"."Person Number" by "Worker"."Assignment Type") / COUNT(*)  ), however it still doesn't give me the correct answer, do you know another way?

Comment: @AdityaMudgal Check the updated answer for an option which doesn't use analytic functions.